# HTML/CSS - Image in div

Tags: css, html, toggle

I'm adding a collapse function to my page, and so far it all works as it should.

I use my header text (h2) to toggle the function like this:

```
   <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('collapse_002')"><h2>Header 1</h2></a>
```

---

Now, I want to add an image to the start of this. When collapsed, it's a plus-sign image. When opened, it turns into a minus-sign image.

How do I do this?
I think I've got the css part figured out, and the function (code below), but just not sure how to get the images to show.

---

```
.toggleButton{
display:inline;
background-image:url(Special_images/pluss3.gif);
background-size:auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.toggleButton.open{
display:inline;
background-image:url(Special_images/minus.gif);
background-size:auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

---

```
<!-- SCRIPT FOR TOGGLE BUTTONS -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggleButton').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
});

</script>
<!-- END -->
```

---

What I'm trying now, that doesnt work:

```
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('collapse_001')"><div class="toggleButton"><h2>Header 1</h2></div></a>
```

---

---

Thanks a lot in advance,
Stian Berg Larsen

EDIT:

This is one of the collapsing divs:

```
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('collapse_002')"><h2>The Operator in Focus</h2></a>
<div id="collapse_002">
<p>content goes here.. Bla bla bla bla....</p>
</div>
```

So this works as it should. When you click on the header the div slides out, showing the text within the div "collapse_002".

Now what I want is to display an image in front of the header, showing either a plus-sign or minus-sign if the div is open or closed.

Comment: **notice:** `h2` is not allowed to put in the `a` until `a` has `display: inline` and `h2` has `display: block` style

Comment: Could you provide all the HTML that you're using?

Comment: To fix that, just use the `onclick` attribute to fire your events, rather than using the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I cant provide all the code, but I can give you the code I'm using for the collapsing divs (this function works. I just need to add an image to the start to indicate + or - / open or closed).

I'll edit in one block of the code.

Comment: @Titanium: I'll give that a try. Though, the image is not showing if I define it in the css, only when I actually add it as an <img> tag in front of the header (whithin the <a> tag). Any ideas?

Comment: @haynar With HTML5, [this is now legal](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/). `<a>` is the only exception to the rule.

Comment: @haynar: Works when I set it to display:block in the css... Thanks! And thanks to the rest of you too! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made you a very simple image swap, using toggle, adding open class..basically just swopping background images :

http://jsfiddle.net/934bA/

**Please ignore temp background urls and sizes*

Let me know if there is something else.

I hope this gives your the base understanding and that it's very simple...it's basically just an add of and class, and remove of a class = toggle.

**BREAKDOWN :**

**Html**

```
<div class="toggleButton"><h2>Header 1</h2></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggleButton').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.toggleButton{
    display:inline;
    background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/35/Plus_sign.jpg);
    background-size:20%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    padding:20px;
}

.open{
    background-image:url(http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/3850515.jpg);
}

h2 {margin:0px; padding:0px;display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
margin:0;
padding-left:16px;
float:left;
background-image:url(images/add.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;      
    }

p.down {
float:left;
padding-left:16px;
background-image:url(images/delete.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
.button         
{
vertical-align:middle;
 } 
.question div   
{
border:1px solid #CC0000;
background-color:#efefef;
width:580px;
margin-top:5px;
font-size:12px;
padding:5px;
clear:left;
 } 
.question div a 
{
padding-left:20px;
background: transparent url(images/world_go.png) no-repeat center left;
text-decoration:none;
 } /

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.question')
    .children('div').hide().end()
    .children('p').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('down').next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});

<div class="question">

<p class="button">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. &nbsp;</p>

<div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. 

<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna.  </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
<li>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu felis vitae dui faucibus pretium. Proin gravida, nisi vitae facilisis egestas, arcu mi adipiscing magna. </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

This is a toggle with plus minus for the front of the paragraph, with a collapse toggle of the paragraph below.

Comment: So many good answers here. I cant accept more than one though =/ But thanks a lot for your help here! I'll keep it all in mind when doing this kind of stuff =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tried background-position: 0 0; ?

Comment: i did set it to left, and it worked (when changing from inline to block.). Thanks mate!